# SQL Server XQuery - Selecting a Subset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

Take for example the following XML:

**Initial Data**

```
<computer_book>
    <title>Selecting XML Nodes the Fun and Easy Way</title>
    <isbn>9999999999999</isbn>
    <pages>500</pages>
    <backing>paperback</backing>
</computer_book>
```

and:

```
<cooking_book>
    <title>50 Quick and Easy XML Dishes</title>
    <isbn>5555555555555</isbn>
    <pages>275</pages>
    <backing>paperback</backing>
</cooking_book>
```

I have something similar in a single xml-typed column of a SQL Server 2008 database. Using SQL Server XQuery, would it be possible to get results such as this:

**Resulting Data**

```
<computer_book>
    <title>Selecting XML Nodes the Fun and Easy Way</title>
    <pages>500</pages>
</computer_book>
```

and:

```
<cooking_book>
    <title>50 Quick and Easy XML Dishes</title>
    <isbn>5555555555555</isbn>
</cooking_book>
```

Please note that I am not referring to selecting both examples in one query; rather I am selecting each via its primary key (which is in another column). In each case, I am essentially trying to select the root and an arbitrary subset of children. The roots can be different, as seen above, so I do not believe I can hard-code the root node name into a "for xml" clause.

I have a feeling SQL Server's XQuery capabilities will not allow this, and that is fine if it is the case. If I can accomplish this, however, I would greatly appreciate an example.

Comment: Do you want to parse XML with differing roots? If so, why mention FOR XML?

Comment: > If so, why mention FOR XML?  This was my fault. I mixed in a response I got on another forum. That solution would not fit my needs due to the roots possibly being different. I simply want to ignore certain children when I return the data from the DB. This was an attempt to reduce the amount of unneeded data being returned from the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the test data I used in the queries below:

```
declare @T table (XMLCol xml)

insert into @T values 
('<computer_book>
    <title>Selecting XML Nodes the Fun and Easy Way</title>
    <isbn>9999999999999</isbn>
    <pages>500</pages>
    <backing>paperback</backing>
  </computer_book>'), 
('<cooking_book>
    <title>50 Quick and Easy XML Dishes</title>
    <isbn>5555555555555</isbn>
    <pages>275</pages>
    <backing>paperback</backing>
  </cooking_book>')
```

You can filter the nodes under to root node like this using local-name() and a list of the node names you want:

```
select XMLCol.query('/*/*[local-name()=("isbn","pages")]')
from @T
```

Result:

```
<isbn>9999999999999</isbn><pages>500</pages>
<isbn>5555555555555</isbn><pages>275</pages>
```

If I understand you correctly the problem with this is that you don't get the root node back.

This query will give you an empty root node:

```
select cast('<'+XMLCol.value('local-name(/*[1])', 'varchar(100)')+'/>' as xml)
from @T
```

Result:

```
<computer_book />
<cooking_book />
```

From this I have found two solutions for you.

**Solution 1**

Get the nodes from your table to a table variable and then modify the XML to look like you want.

```
-- Table variable to hold the node(s) you want
declare @T2 table (RootNode xml, ChildNodes xml)

-- Fetch the xml from your table
insert into @T2
select cast('<'+XMLCol.value('local-name(/*[1])', 'varchar(100)')+'/>' as xml), 
       XMLCol.query('/*/*[local-name()=("isbn","pages")]')
from @T

-- Add the child nodes to the root node
update @T2 set
  RootNode.modify('insert sql:column("ChildNodes") into (/*)[1]')  

-- Fetch the modified XML
select RootNode
from @T2
```

Result:

```
RootNode
<computer_book><isbn>9999999999999</isbn><pages>500</pages></computer_book>
<cooking_book><isbn>5555555555555</isbn><pages>275</pages></cooking_book>
```

The sad part with this solution is that it does not work with SQL Server 2005.

**Solution 2**

Get the parts, build the XML as a string and cast it back to XML.

```
select cast('<'+XMLCol.value('local-name(/*[1])', 'varchar(100)')+'>'+ 
            cast(XMLCol.query('/*/*[local-name()=("isbn","pages")]') as varchar(max))+
            '</'+XMLCol.value('local-name(/*[1])', 'varchar(100)')+'>' as xml)
from @T
```

Result:

```
<computer_book><isbn>9999999999999</isbn><pages>500</pages></computer_book>
<cooking_book><isbn>5555555555555</isbn><pages>275</pages></cooking_book>
```

**Making the nodes parameterized**

In the queries above the nodes you get as child nodes is hard coded in the query. You can use `sql:varaible()` to do this instead. I have not found a way of making the number of nodes dynamic but you can add as many as you think you need and have `null` as value for the nodes you don't need.

```
declare @N1 varchar(10)
declare @N2 varchar(10)
declare @N3 varchar(10)
declare @N4 varchar(10)

set @N1 = 'isbn'
set @N2 = 'pages'
set @N3 = 'backing'
set @N4 = null

select cast('<'+XMLCol.value('local-name(/*[1])', 'varchar(100)')+'>'+ 
            cast(XMLCol.query('/*/*[local-name()=(sql:variable("@N1"),
                                                  sql:variable("@N2"),
                                                  sql:variable("@N3"),
                                                  sql:variable("@N4"))]') as varchar(max))+
            '</'+XMLCol.value('local-name(/*[1])', 'varchar(100)')+'>' as xml)
from @T
```

Result:

```
<computer_book><isbn>9999999999999</isbn><pages>500</pages><backing>paperback</backing></computer_book>
<cooking_book><isbn>5555555555555</isbn><pages>275</pages><backing>paperback</backing></cooking_book>
```

Comment: I had a feeling it would come down to something of this manner. I had wanted to avoid something like an involved concatenation query, though, for the sake of those coming behind me--at the risk of sounding rude and egotistical, those who might be coming behind me aren't the most skilled developers (not my words!). I'm going to leave this open a bit longer to see if there might be a single x.query() version, but if not, I'll mark yours correct. Thanks.